# Best Practice regarding VC Runtime

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, msvcrt

Let us take VS 2010 as example. I have an app and that needs to be deployed on the end user's system. I have the following algorithm:

> 1) If the code is built using Visual Studio 2010 (without SP1) then
>   the installer needs to check/install atleast VC++ 2010 runtime
>   **10.0.30319**.
>
> 2) If the code is built using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 then the
>   installer needs to check/install at-least VC++ 2010 runtime
>   **10.0.40219**.

I know that the latest Service Pack(SP) of VC++ 2010 runtime would support the apps developed using non-SP/old SP Visual Studio 2010.

Thus, is it not the best practice to install the latest version of VC++ Runtime on the end user machine, irrespective of the Service-Pack-status of Visual Studio? I feel this will be the safer option when it comes to security etc..

Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the VC runtime as yet another module in the system, not different from a regular application for the aspect that interests you. Just like for an application, in general you should always have the latest version since it should (at least in theory) be more stable, has more features and less bugs. That said, if you know that a specific version contains a critical bug or a change that interferes with your usage model (e.g., it was freeware and became shareware), you should skip it or adopt your software accordingly.